# Configuring Test Controller

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, integration-testing

I added the TestController user which belongs to appropriate security groups. After that I click test and see that it's ok.
Now I click Apply Settings and it finishes saying that:

1. Failed to configure TFS Team Project Collection.
2. Failed to remove this test controller from TFS Team Project Collection.
3. Failed to clear load test database configuration.

So the final result is that settings (user and password) are not applied.
The point is that in my scenario I don't need to stick Controller to TFS. That's why I didn't set any settings in the Team Project Collection section (as well as in the Load testing section). So why does the program warn me about all that stuff?

Answer (score 0):

This could be a bug in the cleanup. Cleanup of previous configurations is done before attempting to start a fresh configuration. Did you configure this machine earlier against a tfs or with other settings?

You can try to unconfigure the controller via the commandline before configuring it again.

```
testcontrollerconfig.exe delete
```

You will find this exe in the install path. Run the command from an admin command prompt and then try your configuration again.